# Can I source control bamboo plan steps in GIT

Tags: git, bamboo

Is there a way or **plugin** to source control bamboo plan steps in GIT?

Comment: Bamboo is a continuous delivery system. What steps would you want to put in source control? Also Bamboo is from Atlassian who produce Bitbucket, a Git server; I'd suggest asking Atlassian support as well.

Comment: I would like to source control all the steps related to project. This is a like a precautionary step to avoid problems when Bamboo fails/crashes. Thanks @ Schwern

Comment: It sounds like you just want a backup you can restore from?

Comment: Yes, I would like to store as the backup

Comment: Git is not a good backup solution. There's any number of ways to backup a server, and Bamboo itself may have its own backups. Have you tried contacting Atlassian?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bamboo specs as per [this tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-bamboo-specs-yaml-stored-in-bitbucket-server-941616819.html), otherwise no.